# Retrieve value from textfield using a button

Tags: java, javascript, button, applet, textfield

I'm trying to make a text-based rpg using javascript. I currently have a script that can run by itself; as in it's completely automated and receives no input from the player. But I want to make it so that I can take the value from a textfield when the user pushes the button. So for example, if the user enters attack into the textfield and presses the button, it'll go to a attack function. Pretty much what I'm trying to do is turn one of my Java applets into javascript. So first, here's the java applet code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author C.C
 */
public class slime extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    Random rng = new Random();
    int choice;
    int player = 100;
    int king = 100;
    int slime = 50;
    /**
     * Initializes the applet slime
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        initComponents();
        choice = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
        if(choice >=7)
        {
            battle.append("You are the hero. You have 100 health." + "\n");
            battle.append("You encountered a King Slime!" + "\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            battle.append("You are the hero. You have 100 health." + "\n");
            battle.append("You encountered a slime!" + "\n\n");
        }
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        battle = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        attack = new javax.swing.JButton();
        heal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        charge = new javax.swing.JButton();
        run = new javax.swing.JButton();

        battle.setColumns(20);
        battle.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(battle);

        attack.setText("Attack");
        attack.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                attackActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        heal.setText("Heal");
        heal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                healActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        charge.setText("Charge");
        charge.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                chargeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        run.setText("Run");
        run.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                runActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(heal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(attack, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(charge, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(run, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(attack)
                    .addComponent(charge))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(heal)
                    .addComponent(run))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void attackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int damage = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           attack.setEnabled(false);
           battle.setEnabled(false);
           charge.setEnabled(false);
           heal.setEnabled(false);
       }
       else
       {
            if(damage >=7)
            {
                battle.append("You did "+ String.valueOf(damage)+ " damage. It was a critcal hit!" + "\n");
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                battle.append("You did "+ String.valueOf(damage)+ " damage." + "\n");
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The Slime King hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
            }
       }
    }                                      

    private void healActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        int heal = rng.nextInt(40)+20;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           attack.setEnabled(false);
           battle.setEnabled(false);
           charge.setEnabled(false);
       }
       else
       {
           battle.append("You healed for " + heal + " health.\n");
           player = player+heal;
           if (choice >=7)
                {               
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");       
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
       }
    }                                    

    private void chargeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int damage = rng.nextInt(30)+10;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           attack.setEnabled(false);
           battle.setEnabled(false);
           charge.setEnabled(false);
           heal.setEnabled(false);
       }
       else
       {
            battle.append("You skip a turn to charge a more powerful attack!" +"\n");
            if (choice >=7)
                {               
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");       
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            if(player <=0)
            {
                battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
                attack.setEnabled(false);
                battle.setEnabled(false);
                charge.setEnabled(false);
                heal.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    battle.append("You unleash a powerful attack at the King Slime for " + damage + " damage.\n");
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("You unleash a powerful attack at the slime for " + damage + " damage.\n");
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        attack.setEnabled(false);
                        battle.setEnabled(false);
                        charge.setEnabled(false);
                        heal.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            }

       }
    }                                      

    private void runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        if (player==0)
        {
            battle.append("Running won't do you any good when you are dead. \n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            battle.append("You can't run in this game you sissy.\n\n");
        }
    }                                   

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton attack;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea battle;
    private javax.swing.JButton charge;
    private javax.swing.JButton heal;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton run;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is what my javascript file looks like currently:

```
//Player Function
var players = function(attack, health){
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
};

//Make Player Here
var player = new players(50, 1000);

//Monster Function
var monsters = function(attack, health){
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
};

//Make Monsters Here
var kingSlime = new monsters(100, 300);
var slime = new monsters(25, 100);
var slimeWarrior = new monsters(50, 200);

//Make String Names Here
var names;

//Make randomnumber Here
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random(10)*10);

//Make selectedmonster Here
var selectedmonster;
if (randomnumber >= 0 && randomnumber < 3){
    selectedmonster = kingSlime;
    names = "King Slime";
}
else if (randomnumber > 3 && randomnumber < 6){
    selectedmonster = slime;
    names = "Slime";
}
else if (randomnumber > 6){
    selectedmonster = slimeWarrior;
    names = "Slime Warrior";
}
//Battle Script
var battle = 1;
var monsterdead = 0;
var playerdead = 0;
//player goes first, playerturn = 1
var playerturn = 1;
var monsterturn = 0;
while (battle == 1){
//Player's Turn
while (playerturn == 1){
    //Write Player Attack Script    
    selectedmonster.health = selectedmonster.health - Math.ceil(Math.random(player.attack)*10);
    document.write(names + "'s Health is now " + selectedmonster.health+"<br>");
    playerturn = 0;
    monsterturn = 1;
}
//Monster's Turn
while (monsterturn == 1){
    //Write Monster Attack Script
    player.health = player.health - Math.ceil(Math.random(selectedmonster.attack)*10);
    document.write("Player's Health is now " + player.health+"<br>");
    playerturn = 1;
    monsterturn = 0;
}
//When Monster Dies
if (selectedmonster.health < 0){
    document.write("You beat the " + names + "!<br>");
    monsterdead = 1;
    battle = 0;
}
//When Player Dies
if (player.health < 0){
    document.write("You have died.<br>");
    playerdead = 1;
    battle = 0;
}
}
```

So any idea as to how I can add player interaction in the javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="Attack()"> Attack</button>

var userValue = document.getElementById("my inputs id");


function Attack(){
   if(userValue.value = "what im looking for")
     {
        execute attack
     }
}
```